Explicit solution of a ODE in $\mathbb{R}$
Let $g : (0, +\infty) \to (0, +\infty)$ continuous. Given $h \in L^2( \mathbb{R})$, I know there exists a unique $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ weak solution of
$$
(1) \hspace{5mm} -\left( f''(s) + \frac{1}{s} f'(s) \right) + g(s) f(s) = g(s) h(s), \mathbb{R}.
$$
It comes from the Riesz Representation Theorem, that is, formally if we define $u(x) = h(|x|)$ and $V(x) = g(|x|)$, I know how to obtain a radial solution $v(x) = f(|x|) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of
$$
(2) \hspace{5mm} -\Delta v(x) + V(x) v(x) =  V(x) u(x), \mathbb{R}^2
$$
and, as mentioned here,
$$
\Delta v(x) = f''(|x|) + \frac{1}{|x|} f'(|x|).
$$
The existence of solution for  equation (2) is not the problem for me. My question regards on a explicitly solution of (1). Precisely, I would like to know if equation $(1)$ is known in Theory of ODE and if it has a explicitly solution under additional conditions on $g$ or $h$?
Edit: How about if we consider $g(s) = s^{a}$ for some $a > 0$? In this case, $(1)$ reads
$$
- \frac{1}{s^a} f''(s) - \frac{1}{s^{a+1}} f'(s) + f(s) = h(s).
$$

I am a little confused. When $h = 0$, the unique solution should be the null one.
